# C# 7 pattern matching semantics

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, c#-7.0

I have the two blocks of code that I would like to think are equal:

First the `if` based block
[image: IF based code]

Then the exact same but converted to switch case over types.
(sorry for bad Resharper red squiggly markers, Resharper doesnt understand this yet)

[image: SWITCH based code]

The switch based code will throw a Null reference exception on the first `return Actor.Done` which is not null.

Is this a pattern match bug or is there some semantics that I am missing here?

**[edit]**
I've found a fix for it..

Changing this:

```
case MessageEnvelope env:
```

to

```
case MessageEnvelope _:
    var env = m as MessageEnvelope;
```

Makes it all work.
So that leaves me with the question, arn't those lines supposed to be exctly the same?

Comment: First is comparing against 'Started' and 2nd is comparing 'Started.msg'.

Comment: no. "msg" is the name of the typed variable in the patternmatch... there is no "." in there

Comment: Have you tried using a breakpoint inside the switch to see what the actual values are?

Comment: Yes, i has the correct values but throws directly on the "case" match.

Comment: I can't see what is behind the red-line in the image.  Not matter what is there you aren't comparing the same things in the 1st and 2nd case.

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/   section "Switch statements with patterns" .. the "msg" is the typed variable to use in the scope of the case...

Comment: Updated question. the problem is in the `case MessageEnvelope env:` match.. still not sure why that is a problem

Comment: I looks like a compiler bug, `switch` version should work the same way as `if`s, have you tried to report it to Roslyn's github?

Comment: Is there any special reason for posting screenshots instead of plain text formatted as code, except wasting bandwidth or presenting your color scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug when you capture (in a lambda) a pattern variable that was declared in a switch statement. See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16066