# c# 7 pattern matching with unrelated dynamic part

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Let's suppose we have the following (theoretical) code

```
Func<object, dynamic, bool> f1 = (o, d) => o is Person p && p.Name == d && p.Age == 11;

Func<object, dynamic, bool> f2 = (o, d) => o is Person p && p.Age == 11 && p.Name == d;
```

In the first line I'm getting "Use of unassigned local variable p". The highlighted p is in `p.Age == 11`. The second one doesn't produce any errors.

I read that there are some limitations for `dynamic` in pattern matching, but this shouldn't be relevant in this case as the only difference is the order.

Am I missing something?

Some specifics are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45866739/non-shortcircuting-boolean-operators-and-c-sharp-7-pattern-matching) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504414/c-sharp-7-pattern-matching-semantics), but I'm unsure if these are applicable to this situation.

Comment: This is not valid c# code: `o is Person p`. Even if its not c#7. You need to read on how to use `is`

Comment: @CodingYoshi it is valid code.  its a new language feature.

Comment: The `is` expression pattern matching enhancement http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-pattern-matching-in-c-sharp-7-0/

Comment: Since the behavior is clearly a bug -- the compiler produces an error on the very same variable that worked fine in a use of that variable that _precedes_ the usage causing the error, and variables aren't supposed to go from being definitely-assigned to not-definitely-assigned -- and since the bug doesn't happen when using the non-short-circuiting `&` operator, it's pretty clear to me that your scenario is in fact an exact duplicate of the other post you'd seen. Why in this case `dynamic` triggers the bug I can't say; bugs are funny that way-you'd have to ask the person who eventually fixes it

Comment: FWIW, IMHO the use of `dynamic` here is an abuse of that feature anyway. There are more efficient ways to express the same basic logic, even if the parameter to the function is `object` instead of `dynamic`, and I would expect that to be true for any declaration of a method used to instantiate one of these delegates. Why incur the run-time cost of `dynamic` here?

Comment: @PeterDuniho interestingly enough, I don't get any errors for the `if(f && instance is MyClass y) { var x = y; }` only when using `&` or the obvious one with `||`

Comment: Yes. My point is that there's some sort of weird interaction between `dynamic`, operators which may or may not short-circuit, and the new pattern-matching `is`. Your scenario is too coincidentally similar to the other scenario to think that these are in fact two separate bugs in the same feature. They seem certain to me to be two manifestations of the same underlying compiler problem.