# C#7 Pattern Matching value Is Not Null

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, c#-7.0

I'd like to grab the first instance of an enumerable and then perform some actions on that found instance if it exists (`!= null`).  Is there a way to simplify that access with C#7 pattern Matching?

Take the following starting point:

```cs
IEnumerable<Client> clients; /// = new List<Client> {new Client()};
Client myClient = clients.FirstOrDefault();
if (myClient != null)
{
    // do something with myClient
}
```

Can I combine the call to `FirstOrDefault` with the `if statement` something like this:

```cs
if (clients.FirstOrDefault() is null myClient)
{
    // do something with myClient
}
```

I don't see any similar examples on [MSDN Pattern Matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) or [elsewhere on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41504414/1366033)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Absolutely you can do that. My example uses `string` but it would work just the same with `Client`.

```
void Main()
{
    IList<string> list = new List<string>();

    if (list.FirstOrDefault() is string s1) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This won't print as the result is null, " +
                          "which doesn't match string");
    }

    list.Add("Hi!");

    if (list.FirstOrDefault() is string s2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This will print as the result is a string: " + s2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh... off course.  If it's `not null` you can test for whatever it actually **is**  with the affirmative condition.  Thanks!

Comment: make sure list is declared ```var``` or ```IList<string>``` because ```list.Add``` won't work if it's type ```IEnumerable<string>```

Comment: Dammit! The code I originally posted (and actually tested) did have it as List. Then I changed it because he had used IEnumerable, and I wanted to align to his code as closely as possible, to make it clearer to him. Thanks for pointing it out though :-)

Comment: The question is for C#7.0. C#8.0 introduced additional patterns. Since the value is strongly typed as `string`, we do not need to test the type. We could use an empty property pattern to do the test. `list.FirstOrDefault() is { } s1`. Since, for a property pattern to succeed, the object must be not null and we do not actual test any property, `{ }` is equivalent to `!= null` here.

Answer (score 3):

You could potentially use the following null propagation approach as an alternate to RB's answer.

```
var client = clients.FirstOrDefault();
var implement = client?.PerformImplementation();
```

This would automatically perform the null check though the syntax is attempting to utilize the code.  A nice piece of syntactical sugar, condensing the code and still fairly expressive.